# Understanding groupSort and groupOn functions in Data.List.Extra library

Tags: haskell

These are the definitions of `groupSort` and `groupOn` in `Data.List.Extra` module:

```hs
groupSort :: Ord k => [(k, v)] -> [(k, [v])]
groupSort = map (\x -> (fst $ head x, map snd x)) . groupOn fst . sortOn fst
```

```hs
groupOn :: Eq b => (a -> b) -> [a] -> [[a]]
groupOn f = groupBy ((==) `on2` f)
    -- redefine on so we avoid duplicate computation for most values.
    where (.*.) `on2` f = \x -> let fx = f x in \y -> fx .*. f y
```

I would like to know:

- What's the meaning of the comma in `(fst $ head x, map snd x)` ?
- What's the meaning of `(.*.)` inside the definition of `groupOn` ?
- Why is function `on` redefined ? Why is duplicate computation avoided ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's the meaning of the comma in `(fst $ head x, map snd x)`

it constructs a 2-tuple, with `fst (head x)` as first item, and `map snd x` as second item. The lambda expression `\x -> (fst $ head x, map snd x)` thus pas a list of values of the group to a 2-tuple where the first item is the first item of the first 2-tuple of the list, and the second item is a list of all the second item of the list of 2-tuples `xs`.

> What's the meaning of `(.*.)` inside the definition of `groupOn`?

It is the first operand of the `on2` function that is defined in the where clause. One could have defined it with:

```
where on2 g f = \x -> let fx = f x in \y -> g fx (f y)
```

Here we thus renamed the first parameter `g`, and since it is not an operator, we thus do not use infix notation like `fx .*. f y`, but write `g fx (f y)`.

In case of the `groupBy`, then `(.*.)` is thus the same as `(==)`, and this thus means that `` (==) `on2` f `` is the same as:

```
(==) `on2` f = \x -> let fx = f x in \y -> fx == f y
```

It is thus a function that determines when two items are considered to be in the same group.

> Why is function `on` redefined? Why is duplicate computation avoided?

It aims to avoid computing `f` on the first item multiple times. It does this once, and stores this in a variable `fx` to avoid recomputing it for each next element where we want to check if it belongs to same group.

The `groupBy` function is [implemented as [src]](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/src/Data.OldList.html#groupBy):

```
groupBy                 :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]
groupBy _  []           =  []
groupBy eq (x:xs)       =  (x:ys) : groupBy eq zs
                           where (ys,zs) = span (eq x) xs
```

Here it will thus calculate `eq x` to generate a function that matches the following elements. By calling `eq x`, it will thus call the function with the first item of the group that it is constructing, and the `let` statements will ensure that `let fx = f x in …`, this thus means that `f x` is no longer calculated.

Of course `on2` will still evaluate `f x` for all the next elements that will be matched to the group. This thus means that if you are writing:

```
groupOn (+1) [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1]
```

it will check the following elements of the list, we will evaluate this as `fx`:

```
             [1,        2,        1      ]
```

For the following elements we will evaluate this as `f y`:

```
             [  1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1]
```

as second operand. So we still evaluate `f` on each element of the list at least once, and for each start of a new group (except the first one) we will evaluate it twice.

For a list of *n* elements with *n>0* that is divided in *g* groups, it will evaluate `f` *n+g-1* times.

Comment: Maybe it’s worth noting that `span f` will evaluate `f` multiple times, once for each element in the list (until it no longer returns `True` of course).

Comment: @bradrn: yes good point! I think that for a list with *n* elements that eventually generates *g* groups, it will likely call `f` *n+g-1* times on the elements of the list.

Answer (score 2):

> What's the meaning of the comma in `(fst $ head x, map snd x)` ?

It’s just a tuple, exactly the same as in something like `(1, 2)`. (It might be clearer to rewrite it as `(fst (head x), map snd x)`.)

> What's the meaning of `(.*.)` inside the definition of `groupOn` ?

It’s just a particularly clever (though not particularly readable) way of defining the first argument of `on2`. That is, the following two definitions are equivalent:

```
(.*.) `on2` f = \x -> let fx = f x in \y -> fx .*. f y
g     `on2` f = \x -> let fx = f x in \y -> fx `g` (f y)
```

> Why is function `on` redefined ? Why is duplicate computation avoided ?

I’m honestly not sure… I can see no particular advantages to redefining `on` here. (I’m not even sure what ‘duplicate computation’ they’re talking about! If someone else has any idea why they’re doing this, feel free to add a comment.)